# Counting the number of zero in an integer

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

The program would ask the user an integer input.
and it counts how many zero the int has.
constraints: use while loop

ex:
input: 2400
count: 2

now I have no problem in that part, only when the user would input a zero.
supposed it counts 1.

ex:
input 0
count: 1

but then the program returns count 0.

here's the code:

```
int main(){
    int n, counter = 0;
    
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    while(n != 0){
        if(n % 10 == 0){
            counter ++;
            n=n/10;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
      
      printf("%d", counter);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the expected output for 10200?

Comment: let me edit the question... i forgot to include constraints, only while loop is allowed to be used

Comment: do while is still a while loop in any ways. But if teacher told you that you can't use it, it means they want to teach you something by it

Comment: `int counter = (n == 0);` and nothing else.. (Although that `break` means you'll miss counting the 0 in 1024...) More unpublished constraints?

Comment: user3386109
interestingly it only counts the zeros after 2
so output is 
count: 2

Comment: yes he should remove that ´Break´

Comment: You break out of your loop as soon as you find the first digit that is not a 0. You should not do that. If the digit is not 0, just don't increment the counter and continue with your loop. Regarding the input `0` you will need an extra `if` to handle that case. Or that initialization mentioned by Fe2O3

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to use a `do`/`while` loop.  That's what I'd use, arbitrary restrictions be damned.

Comment: Why do you convert a string (the input) into an `int` to later extract the digits, one by one with modulo and divisions if you had it from the first time as ascii digits?.

Comment: 1) discover what you need to do (e.g) do you count leading zeros).

Answer (score 0):

You have `while(n != 0)` this does so when you enter just 0 it doesn't run. So the counter that you have set to 0 at the beginning is still 0

Here is what I would have done :

```
 int main()
{
    int num, count = 0;
    
    scanf("%d",&num);
    
    
    if (num == 0) {
        printf("1");
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    while(num != 0) //do till num greater than  0
    {
        
        int mod = num % 10;  //split last digit from number
        num = num / 10;    //divide num by 10. num /= 10 also a valid one 
        if(mod == 0) count ++;
    
    
    }
     printf("%d\n",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Just don't forget to consider everything that can happen with a condition that you set

**Fixed it

Comment: yep i tried replacing it with while( n > 0) but still does the same

Comment: well the thing is that 0 is 0 so it can't be bigger than 0 so the condition hasn't been fulfilled. Try this >=

Comment: the print doesnt even post so with while( n >= 0)

Comment: you also have issue with n if they have a 0 in the middle of the number, for example 2022, it won't count the 0 in there

Comment: I added what I would have done myself for that assignment

Comment: Add an if statement which sets count to 1 if n is 0 otherwise run the while loop.

Comment: yeah forgot about it XD, Fixed

Comment: dows not work https://godbolt.org/z/5h1hGcvnG

Comment: ah if you want to have negative numbers too you can use the if (num != 0) {...}

Answer (score 0):

1. Use functions.

```
int countZeroes(int x)
{
    int result = !x;   // if x == 0 then result = 1

    while(x)
    {
        result += !(x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", countZeroes(0));
    printf("%d\n", countZeroes(1000));
    printf("%d\n", countZeroes(-202020));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/91hKr46eo

Comment: it's a good one, the issue is that we need to "dumb it down" because this is clearly an assignment, if they need help for this it means that they don't know how to code at all so I'm guessing that it won't do

Answer (score 0):

A different version that prints the integer as a string, and looks for '0' characters in it. Tested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int input = 0;
    int zeroes = 0;
    char *foundpos, teststring[100];

    scanf("%d", &input);
    sprintf(teststring, "%d", input);

    foundpos = strchr(teststring, '0');
    while (foundpos != NULL) {
        ++zeroes;
        foundpos = strchr(foundpos + 1, '0');
    }
    printf("%d contains %d zeroes", input, zeroes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count the zero digits you get between `\n` chars.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ndigs = 0, c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
        case '0':  ndigs++; 
                   break;
        case '\n': printf(" => %d zero digs", ndigs);
                   ndigs = 0;
                   break;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

sample output:

```
$ ./a.out
123001202010  
123001202010 => 5 zero digs
^D
$ _
```

No need to convert digits to a number, to convert it back to decimal digits.  You can improve the program counting digits until a nondigit is detected, then output.  But there's no need to convert a decimal representation of a number (in base 10) to internal representation to then get the digits you have destroyed (in the conversion) back again to count them.

Answer (score -1):

As earlier mentioned, the problem is with the loop:

```c
while(n != 0){
        if(n % 10 == 0){
            counter ++;
            n=n/10;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
```

It doesnt do anything in case n == 0. But replacing it with n > 0 is not a good solution because ints can be negative too.
You should use do{}while() construction instead, it will always do one iteration of loop no matter what condition you put there. Notice that no matter what you get as a number, it is still a number so you can do one iteration of loop either way.
Just do as follows:

```c
do{
        if(n % 10 == 0){
            counter ++;
            n=n/10;
        }else{
            break;
        }
} while( n != 0 );
```

This should work(if i didnt mess up the braces/semicolumns).

Comment: no it will not work